# Second default gateway on demand?

Tags: networking, gateway

I am in to a strange network setup,

Hosts on the secure network, are all under a domain and use various services on the domain. When ever the need to access web application on the more secure network they log in to virtual machines that have default gateway the router on the border between the secure and more secure network.

The rest of the traffic to the outside world is happening through the ASA cisco 5505 (so natively) the hosts have default gateway the ASA.

Now, is there any more convenient way to connect to the web application on the more secure network without the need of virtual machines?

Before you reply with DMZ configuration on the ASA, I have to say that this is not an option.

Any Ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: This would really depend on the security requirements. It is trivial to add a route to the secure network on the hosts, but it means the hosts can access the secure server and the internet at the same time and this can be considered less secure than the virtual machine solution (strongly depends on the setup of the VM).

Comment: It's not a second default gateway, but another gateway for a specific network. In any case, host/server/VM configurations are off-topic here. You could ask about that on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Static Route on Your computer. In windows Operating System you can use `route add` command.

for example

```
route -p add 10.19.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 10.10.0.1
```

[click here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-intelligent-contact-management-enterprise/20524-route-command.html)

Comment: That was all? It was super easy and works great as I tested it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes. If you want to be more secure, you can configure remote site SSL or IPsec VPN